# What is $\langle 0|p\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, quantum-states, normalization

$\hat{p}$ is the generator of the translation group, so $$|r\rangle=e^{-ir\hat{p}/\hbar}|0\rangle\to\langle p|r\rangle=e^{-irp/\hbar}\langle p|0\rangle.$$ Assuming normalized position states
\begin{gather*}
1
=
\langle r|r\rangle
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\frac{\text{d}p}{2\pi\hbar}
\langle r|p\rangle
\langle p|r\rangle
\\
2\pi\hbar
=
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\text{d}p
|\langle 0|p\rangle|^2
\end{gather*}
So seems that $\langle 0|p\rangle$ cannot be constant and that it's not of trivial calculation: how can I find it?

Comment: It is a very basilar question and I'm sure somebody already asked it: it's days I'm looking for an answer and I still can not find it. Thanks for any suggestion and help.

Comment: the normalization you are using is inadequate for continuous basis such as position space or momentum space which is implied by your integration. The correct normalization is $\langle r | r'\rangle = \delta(r-r')$

Comment: @yyy Right, embarassing error, I got stuck on deltas and when I did internal product I just threw away $\delta(0)$... After 8 years of physics the same errors of day 1...

Comment: For summary, [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation#The_unit_operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work in $d$-dimensional space.

Because position is continuous with support $\Bbb R^d$, the orthonormality condition on position eigenkets is not $\langle r|s\rangle=\delta_{rs}$ with a Kronecker delta on the RHS, but rather $\langle r|s\rangle=\delta^{(d)}(r-s)$ with a Dirac delta on the RHS, as @yyy noted. So $\langle r|r\rangle$ is $\delta^{(d)}(0)$, not $1$.

It's best to look at the general case, viz.$$\langle r|s\rangle=\int_{\Bbb R^d}\langle r|p\rangle\langle p|s\rangle\Bbb d^dp=\int_{\Bbb R^d}h^{-d}e^{ip\cdot(r-s)/\hbar}\Bbb d^dp=\delta^{(d)}(r-s).$$

Comment: Right, I confused the deltas! But how can I find $\langle 0|p\rangle$ now?

Comment: @RobTan As discussed in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Fourier_transform) section (although the whole article is worth a read), $\langle x|p\rangle=h^{-d/2}e^{ix\cdot p/\hbar}$, which fits your relation with $\langle 0|p\rangle=h^{-d/2}$.

Comment: I think I can use the fact that $F(\delta)=1$, where $F$ is the Fourier transform, right?

Comment: @RobTan Yes. In fact, you could deduce $\langle x|p\rangle$ from the requirement$$\langle r|s\rangle=\delta^{(d)}(r-s)=\int_{\Bbb R^d}(2\pi)^{-d}e^{ik\cdot(r-s)}\Bbb d^dk.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was like one month that I was stuck on this.

Comment: @RobTan If I can give one piece of advice to not spend a month like this again, always do the general case rather than the diagonal case, e.g. consider $\langle r|s\rangle$ rather than $\langle r|r\rangle$.

Comment: I thank you for your advice. I did the general case and the multidimensional one, I also saw again my notes on QFT where there wasn't this kind of problem (many many more, but not this one!). Now, with path integrals, I'm just asking myself where $\langle 0|p\rangle$ is going. Maybe I'm becoming functional illiterate, or maybe too many years of physics fried some neurons in my brain, I really can't tell. Thank you again and have a nice day :)